# Is it allowed in iOS to redirect user to website for payment?

Tags: ios, swift, payment, wkwebview

I asked this question at stack exchange but couldn't get any reply therefor posting it here so that I can get some help.

I am developing an iOS app for selling physical goods and for that, I want to redirect my user to my website for checkout and payment process. I want to confirm if that is allowed by apple guidelines. I tried to check with apple support but couldn't get a satisfactory answer. I am not asking about redirecting the user to the PayPal/stripe website but my own website where I have Authorize.net/Paypal integration and want my user to make payment there and then I will take him back to my app. As per my understanding, external payment is allowed for physical goods but I want to check if my use case is acceptable or not.

Comment: Probably. Only Apple can say and probably only after they review your app. You should make sure that you use a web view in your app; don't send the user to Safari

Comment: yes, but better do the payment inside the app on ViewController with web view, to handle all requests

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I am using WKWebView in my view controller to open the redirect URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External payment is **required** for physical goods, you can't pay physical goods using your iTunes account. The only allowed way to pay for physical goods using the Apple infrastructure is using Apple Pay if it's available in your country:

(Excerpt taken from [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/))

> 3.1.5(a) Goods and Services Outside of the App: If your app enables people to purchase goods or services that will be consumed outside of the app, you must use purchase methods other than in-app purchase to collect those payments, such as Apple Pay or traditional credit card entry.

Anyway Apple is quite picky about privacy, security and user experience, so try not to take the user out of the application and make the paying process as secure as you can. I would try to integrate whatever payment gateway you are using inside your app, or at least open a web view inside the app instead of sending the user to Safari with an external URL.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I am not sending the user to safari instead I am using WKWebView in my view controller to open the redirect URL where the user will have multiple options to pay including traditional credit card entry. Also, I am from  India and as per my knowledge, Apple pay is not available in India yet. I referred below link, please correct me If I am wrong.
https://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#apple-pay

Comment: You're welcome. That link is correct. I guess you are already doing it, but make sure the URL is protected with HTTPS and you inform your users about your privacy and security policy.

Comment: is it allowed to make payment through website for services in app ? I am unable to get any documentation for this

Answer (score 0):

Check this documentation of apple . May be you get some help from this
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content